# More Efficient Way to Filter Spark RDD by Summarized List

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD of data that I'm doing some pre-processing/data munging on before I send into a Spark pipe() of R code to do some complex hierarchical modeling. I've got something that works, but it seems clunky and inefficient. I'd love to get two things out of this question, as I'm still learning how to work with Spark data structures in Python, having worked in R for a long time.

1. Are there more efficient ways to do specific parts of this code to make it more efficient?
2. Would it be more efficient to do all of this as a SparkDataFrame as opposed to doing with RDDs?

**Code**

I start by pulling my text file, piping it through an R script that appends a `stixel_id` which is what I will use as the key in groupByKey() later. My goal is to sum another column (`obs`) by `stixel_id` and then filter the whole RDD by a subset of `stixel_id`.

First, pull in the data, append `stixel_id` through the R pipe and munge a little (largely due to legacy formatting).

```
# input format
# u'83278,"train",-76.5018492,42.4622906,2012.8606557377,2012,315,9.25,2,0.805,2,0,112,10,28.2051,17.9487,0,0,10.2564,33.3333,0,0,0,0,2.5641,5.1282,2.5641,0,0'

inp = sc.textFile("ebird.abund_species_all.random.merge.txt", minPartitions=numP*32) \
    .pipe("./0_stixel_keys_SparkHPCWrapper.R") \
    .map(lambda line: line.split("\n")) \
    .filter(lambda p:  p[0].split("\t")[0] != "") \
    .map(lambda p: (p[0].split("\t")[0]+","+p[0].split("\t")[1]))

# output format
# u'1-10-14-8,83278,"train",-76.5018492,42.4622906,0.8606557,2012,315,9.25,2,0.805,2,0,112,10,28.2051,17.9487,0,0,10.2564,33.3333,0,0,0,0,2.5641,5.1282,2.5641,0,0'
```

Next, create a DataFrame with a subset of columns from my RDD.

```
parts = inp.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
rows = parts.map(lambda p: Row(stixel_id=p[0], data_type=p[2], obs=p[29]))
rowsdf = s1.createDataFrame(rows)

# output format
# Row(data_type=u'"train"', obs=u'0', stixel_id=u'1-10-14-8')
```

Next, cast `obs` field to integer, and sum `obs` by `data_type`.

```
rowsdfc = rowsdf.select(rowsdf.stixel_id, rowsdf.data_type, rowsdf.obs.cast("integer"))
sums = rowsdfc.filter(rowsdfc.data_type.like("%train%")) \
    .groupBy(["stixel_id", "data_type"]) \
    .sum("obs") \
    .collect()
sumsdf = s1.createDataFrame(sums)

# output format
# Row(stixel_id=u'4-10-14-8', data_type=u'"train"', sum(obs)=5)
```

Second to last, filter the list of `stixel_id` by `sum(obs) > 5` and create a simple list.

```
sumsdfpos = sumsdf.filter(sumsdf["sum(obs)"] > 5)
stixels = sumsdfpos.select(sumsdfpos.stixel_id)
stixel_list = stixels.select("stixel_id").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
fit_tasks = len(stixel_list)

# output
# [u'2-10-13-7', u'3-11-13-8', u'1-10-13-8', u'3-10-12-7', u'3-10-13-6', u'4-11-14-7', u'4-11-13-9', u'3-11-13-6', u'2-10-13-8', u'2-11-13-7', u'2-10-13-9', u'1-10-13-7', u'4-11-14-8', u'5-11-12-7', u'1-10-14-7', u'5-11-13-8', u'1-9-13-7', u'2-10-13-6', u'1-10-14-8', u'2-11-13-8', u'1-10-13-9', u'5-11-13-7', u'5-10-12-7', u'3-11-12-7', u'2-11-13-6', u'3-10-13-7', u'4-11-13-7', u'5-10-13-7', u'4-10-14-7', u'4-11-13-8', u'3-10-12-6', u'4-10-13-7', u'1-9-14-7', u'5-11-12-8', u'3-11-12-6', u'3-11-13-7']
```

Finally, filter my RDD with `stixel_id` by this list.

```
inpf = inp.filter(lambda p: p.split(",")[0] in stixel_list)

# output format
# u'1-10-14-8,83278,"train",-76.5018492,42.4622906,0.8606557,2012,315,9.25,2,0.805,2,0,112,10,28.2051,17.9487,0,0,10.2564,33.3333,0,0,0,0,2.5641,5.1282,2.5641,0,0'
```

Comment: please share example data and expected output.

Comment: Example data and expected output are provided as comments in each code chunk.